# Error on Userform.Hide inside Workbook_Deactivate event

Tags: excel, hide, userform, excel-2003, vba

As the title say I've been having one particular problem with my userform. When I close it (with a command button) an error pops on Userform.Hide inside the Workbook_Deactivate event.

This is the code on the Userform_initialize event:

*All variables in here are global*

VBA:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    subRemoveCloseButton Me
    Set pagina = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ruta")
    Set libro = Workbooks.Open(pagina.Range("B4").Value, False, True)
    Set pagina2 = libro.Worksheets("GLOBAL")
    pasadas = 0
    If pagina2.AutoFilterMode Then
        If pagina2.FilterMode Then
            pagina2.ShowAllData
        End If
    ElseIf pagina2.FilterMode Then
        pagina2.ShowAllData
    End If
    pagina2.Columns("A:IV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    lastRow = pagina2.Cells(pagina2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Call RemoveDuplicates
    With Me.ImagenDatos
        .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsBoth
        'Change 8.5 to suit your needs
        .ScrollHeight = .InsideHeight * 5
        .ScrollWidth = .InsideWidth * 3
    End With
End Sub
```

Then in the CommandButton_Click event I have this:

VBA:

```
Private Sub BotonCerrar_Click()
    Unload Consultas
    libro.Saved = True
    libro.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The error, as already commented, comes from this:

VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Consultas.Hide
End Sub
```

If I comment that single line the Userform closes with no problem but I need it so the userform (Consultas) hides when the user switches between workbooks.

The error message says: Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

Anyone have a clue on what's going wrong?
This is my first post and if something else is needed just let me know.

I would appreciate any help on this.

EDIT: I have more code but I think this is pretty much the essential as all I do is open the excel workbook, then the userform shows and then I click the button that closes the userform

Comment: Hi IvnBam. Seems to me that you unload the form with that button, then Workbook_Deactivate is called automatically for some reason, and tries to call the Hide method on form that was unloaded. Maybe *On Error Resume Next* before Consultas.Hide would solve the issue? Did you try it?

Comment: You can also check if `Consultas` is still there before trying to hide it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584438/excel-vba-hide-all-opened-userforms

Comment: Hi @A.S.H thanks for your reply. I did try that and then the error moved to the part where I close "libro". Seems like the scope of that variable, eventhough is global, is somehow lost inside the "BotonCerrar_Click()" subroutine

Comment: yes I think that if libro is a member of the form object, it looses scope as well when the form is unloaded. but you can probably solve that by changing the order of things in BotonCerrar_Click() : try closing libro before unloading Consultas.

Comment: Hi @Ralph thank you for replying. I actually tried that but it wasn't what i was looking for since it closed all opened userforms on all opened workbooks. However today when I tried that code again it worked. There wasn't any differences on the code but now it doesn't close the userforms on another workbooks :D

Comment: Many thanks for your help A.S.H and Ralph (: I found a solution for this and all the errors I faced n.n

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I solved this:

Before trying to hide the userform `Consultas` on the `Workbook_Deactivate` event I first checked if the userform was visible with the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584438/excel-vba-hide-all-opened-userforms) provided by @Ralph.

That solved part of the problem but then the error moved to the part where I close `libro` :

```
Private Sub BotonCerrar_Click()
    Unload Consultas
    libro.Saved = True
    libro.Close
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The error persisted even before unloading the userform as suggested by @A.S.H but I fixed it calling `Application.Workbooks(libro.Name).Close False` instead of `libro.close False` (If someone could explain this to me I would really appreciated it)

The final code is the following:

```
Private Sub BotonCerrar_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim otrolibro As Boolean
    otrolibro = False
    Application.Workbooks(libro.Name).Close False
    Unload Consultas
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            otrolibro = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wb
    If otrolibro = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close False
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

The For cicle is to quit the excel application if there is not another Workbook open because if I just close all Workbooks, an Excel window remains open with nothing on it.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. To understand why you had to call *Application.Workbooks(libro.Name)*, we need to know where and how libro is defined. I guess as a Workbook reference in the UserFom module?

Comment: By the way, in the new code you dont assign the *.saved* property before closing false as you did with libro. did you try to do the same with libro? All this is a but strange though, but I have seen even stranger things ;)

Comment: Hi A.S.H. I define libro as Public libro as workbook at the beginning of the userform module outside any subroutine, then I use the variable only in the initialize event of the userform.  And yes, I tried to do the same with libro but the problem is that libro wasn't recognized as a variable. I tried showing its name with "MsgBox libro.name" but the same error prompted.